# Rails post redirecting to show action and not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My code:

```
    def receive
        @flick = Flick.new(  flick_params )
        if @flick.save
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "WTF"
        end
    end

    def show

    end
```

For some reason it's not creating a flick when I call `http://localhost:3000/flicks/receive?user_id=asdadasd` and instead redirecting me to the show action and doing nothing. Not sure why this is happening.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any Error? And post the log after submitting the form

Comment: Not submitting a form and no errors

Comment: Did you check the log? params are coming are not?

Comment: They are but not saving

Comment: Ok Please post the `log` and `flick_params` method.

Comment: And also post the `form` code.

Comment: If you have something that is not auto-generated in config/routes.rb, you might consider sending `rake routes` as well.

Comment: Try @flick.save! - you might have validation errors, using ! Will raise them

Comment: No errors. The problem was I wasn't using a post service like Postman to do the post request so it was going as a get request. That being said, I did have some trouble with postman getting a `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error

Answer (score 2):

If the receive action is a post method, ust specify the  method to post in the create form. It should be something like this,

```
<%= form_for @flick, method: :post do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Just try this, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

```
http://localhost:3000/flicks/receive?user_id=asdadasd
```

That's a `GET` URL

If you've got to include the `user_id` as an attached URL param, I'd strongly recommend using something like [`devise`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) or [`sessions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark) to give you a way to track the `user_id`, so you can access it directly in the controller & not pass through the URL

---

**Form**

In regards to your question, you need to remember that Rails won't just load the `show` action for the sake of it. You'll have some problem causing this issue

My suspicion is you're using `method: :get` in your `form` (as suggested by `Mohanraj`). This is a problem, **your `show` and `create` methods are part of the same [`routing resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resources-on-the-web)**:

```
GET /photos photos#index    display a list of all photos
GET /photos/new photos#new  return an HTML form for creating a new photo
POST    /photos photos#create   create a new photo
GET /photos/:id photos#show display a specific photo
GET /photos/:id/edit    photos#edit return an HTML form for editing a photo
PATCH/PUT   /photos/:id photos#update   update a specific photo
DELETE  /photos/:id photos#destroy  delete a specific photo
```

---

This means if you submit your form with the `GET` request, you're going to get the `show` action

**Fix**

I would recommend trying the answer provided by `Mohanraj`:

```
<%= form_for @var do |f| %> #-> this will default to POST
<% end %>
```